# Trying to Use Powershell Credential Object to Run As Admin?

Tags: powershell, uac, credentials

let me start off by saying that I have scoured through the online resources and cannot figure out how to properly pass admin credentials (user AND password) through my powershell script. I have a script, lets call it script.ps1, and the script looks like this (I have powershell v1.0):

```
$UserName = "domain\user"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ` -ArgumentList $UserName, $Password



$events = Get-WinEvent -Credential $Credentials -ComputerName thecomputername -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational

$resultArry = @()

foreach($ev in $events)
{
  Try
  {
    $evXML = [xml]$ev.ToXml()
    if( $ev.Id -eq 307 )
    {
      $obj = New-Object PSObject
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param3
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Document" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param2
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $evXML.Event.System.Computer
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Event Timestamp" -Value $evXML.Event.System.TimeCreated.GetAttribute("SystemTime")
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Printer" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param5
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Port" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param6
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Pages" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param8
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size in Bytes" -Value $evXML.Event.UserData.DocumentPrinted.Param7
            $script:resultArry += $obj
    }
  }
  Catch
  {
  }
}

$resultArry | Export-CSV C:\mycsv.csv -NoTypeInformation

pause
```

When I double click on this script to run it, I am still getting a permissions denied. I want the admin account to automatically be entered so the script will run as that. If I get rid of the code at the top, and right click on my file and run it as an admin and manually enter my credentials, it will work successfully. I am obviously not using/passing the credentials correctly, so I was hoping someone could see what I am doing wrong?

I don't want to set the icon shortcut to automatically run as an admin when clicked on, because I am having an automated process run this script, and that workaround will not work in this case. I need the actual code to pass the credentials

Thanks for any input, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: Read the following first: [You cannot bypass the UAC prompt](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/21afa490-a74e-4052-8c34-e997cdc593b3/).

Comment: Then I'm curious, what is the point of creating a PSCredential object that has the username and password?

Comment: For passing credentials. Passing credentials != elevation != bypassing the UAC prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So really what I am trying to do is run this code from a C# windows GUI application. It is getting users print logs, and needs the admin account to run it. Do you have any suggestions as to how to get around this?

Comment: You are asking a question about Windows security. I would start by investigating the actual log data you need to read and then research if/how you can read the relevant data without needing to elevate.